# How can I correctly send actual parameters of integers to main() to calculate the sum in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

The book tells me The declaration of the main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

It seems that `int argc, char** argv` are the only things I can send as actual parameters.

Now I don't want to deal with strings main.

I want to calculate the sum of integers sent to main and return the sum.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int n, char** argv) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        char** temp = argv;
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (*temp != NULL) {
                std::cout << i++ << ':' << *temp << std::endl;
                sum += *temp++;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The above is my original thinking that fails to work.

It can't be compiled due to Invalid conversion from char to int

I think argument must be array of argc of pointer to integer.

So following is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int n, int* argv[]) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl; //print the number of the arguments passed
        int** temp = argv;
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (*temp != NULL) {
                std::cout << i++ << ':' << **temp << std::endl;
                if (*temp != argv[0])
                        sum += **temp;
                ++temp;
        }
        std::cout << "The sum of all integered entered is " << sum << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

After compiling the code with GCC, I enter `./a.out 1 2 3`, and I get

```
4
0:778121006
1:3276849
2:3342386
3:1213399091
The sum of all integered entered is 1220018326
```

I know it is far from perfect but it is better than the first one.

I think `temp`(or `argv`) is degraded to pointer to a pointer to an integer.

So `**temp` should be an integer.

**Why the print of `**temp` looks like a pointer?**

**How can I correctly send actual parameters of integers to main to calculate the sum?**

Comment: What is the output of your first attempt?

Comment: You need to convert to int. See [`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).

Comment: You need to leave main as `int n, char** argv` and converts the string in the array to integers.

Comment: Just loop on `argc` convert each `argv[i]` to an `int`, and add.  There is no need for `temp **` or anything like that. The problem seems to be you throw the `argc` value away and don't use it except for printing the value.

Comment: The text that you type at the command line is just that: **text**. When the text is expected to represent a numeric value you have to convert the text into a number.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- the last entry in the `argv` array will always be a null pointer, so looping until you see the null is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the signature of the main function, it will remain the same anyway.
The right signature is :

```
int main(char ac, char **av); // or char *av[] if you prefer
```

ac : argument count
av : argument values

You get only strings as parameter, a chain of characters ended by null byte '\0'.
Also, the first value in av is always the program name itself. Try to print it ;)

Using a simple function you can convert this to a number, there is one for int, float, double, long, unsigned long and unsigned long long.

- std::stoi
- std::stof
- std::stod
- std::stol
- std::stoul
- std::stoull

All of them takes a string as parameter and return the parsed number.

```cpp
for (int i = 1 ; i < ac ; i++) { // we don't want the first value, so we start from 1
   int number = std::stoi(av[i]);
   std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't send integers to main. Instead you convert the strings sent to `main` into integers. You can use the `std::stoi` function for this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     std::cout << argc << std::endl; //print the number of the arguments passed
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
         sum += std::stoi(argv[i]);
     std::cout << "The sum of all integered entered is " << sum << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

In your code `**temp` is printing as an integer, just one with a garbage value. All your code is doing is pretending that you can send integers to main, but you can't so you get garbage output.

Comment: 2nd argument should be `char*[]`.

Comment: @cigien Indeed - I'm certain he just didn't see it when copying from OP so I fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, was just about to edit it myself. Thanks for stepping up :)

Answer (score 1):

Most direct approaches have been covered but I'll throw in another alternative.

The second argument to `main` is an array of `char*`. Each `char*` points at a null terminated C string. This needs to be converted into an `int` somehow. The other answers have covered misc. conversion functions. Here I'll put each C string in a `std::istringstream` and use C++ formatted input to extract the data from the stream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << argc << std::endl; // print the number of the arguments passed

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::istringstream is(argv[i]); // put the argument in a istringstream
        std::cout << i << ':';

        int temp;
        // extract int:s from the stringstream until it's depleated
        while(is >> temp) {
            std::cout << ' ' << temp;
            sum += temp;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "The sum of all integered entered is " << sum << '\n';
}
```

When running this, you can do "fun" stuff like putting two `int`:s in one argument:

Put `1` and `2` in one argument and `3` in the other:

```
./program "1 2" 3
```

Output:

```
3
1: 1 2
2: 3
The sum of all integered entered is 6
```